# Retrieve message from server after an async Axios POST

Tags: javascript, post, async-await, axios

How do I retrieve message from server after calling:

```js
await axios.post(url, data)
```

```js
export const postData = async data => {
  try {
    let url = `${api}auth/register`;
    let res = await axios.post(url, data).catch(e => console.log(e));
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Alert.alert("Error");
  }
};
```

[image: this is response from server]

Now this function is returning `undefined` in console. My motive is to get the message and code from server response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
  axios.post('url')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.message);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answers.

So whenever we call `axios.post` it gives us a `.catch()` function to use. If the server returns a bad status codes like `500` or `400`. The control goes in `.catch()` and do whatever it says to. Since the control is in `.catch()` the function `postData()` does not return anything and remains `undefined`. Now, to retrieve the messages from the server this is what can we do.

`.catch(e => console.log(e.response.data.message))`